# Folders organizer FREE

Tags: windows, knowledge-organization, color, directories

I am looking for organizing software for folders, that can color-coded icons with different colors. I want to organize my desktop with color-coded system for my documents, but don't want every time download colored icons from Internet and don't want to have standard icons for Windows. It is better to be free or something really helpful (a big icon pack in the utility + maybe sorting/filtering features).
I tried Rainbow Folder, but don't like the interface, for me it is not modern. Want to change icons as quickly as possible. Want something like Folder Colorizer but with more icons and features.